# How to merge multiple columns in one in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame called `mydf` with hundreds of paired columns (`value1` to `valueX` and `rec1` to `recX`). I want to combine all these paired columns in the order of their values into value and rec columns as shown in the result. How can I do this in R?

```
    mydf<-structure(list(samples = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", 
"c"), class = "factor"), value1 = c(1, 8, 7), value2 = c(2, 5, 
9), rec1 = c(7158, 6975, 6573), rec2 = c(1122, 2235, 229)), .Names = c("samples", 
"value1", "value2", "rec1", "rec2"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

result

```
sample   value    rec
A         1      7158
A         2      1122
B         5      2235
C         7      6573
B         8      6975
C         9      229
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve this quickly using `data.table`s `melt` method which allows you to specify regex patters within the `measure.vars` argument

```
library(data.table) # v >= 1.9.6
melt(setDT(mydf), measure = patterns("value", "rec"), value.name = c("value", "rec"))
#    samples variable value  rec
# 1:       A        1     1 7158
# 2:       B        1     8 6975
# 3:       c        1     7 6573
# 4:       A        2     2 1122
# 5:       B        2     5 2235
# 6:       c        2     9  229
```